# Change Bottom Toolbar selected button color in Android Studio

Tags: android

This might be a pretty stupid question, but I'm still a newbie so bare with me.

I'm currently trying to make an app where I need a menu toolbar. With android system dark mode enabled, the buttons show up fine (White when selected, gray when deselected). But on android system light mode, the deselected button becomes invisible and only visible when pressed. I just cannot figure out how to solve this issue so any help is appreciated. Below, the first image demonstrated the toolbar on a phone with android system dark mode enabled, and the 2nd image shows the toolbar a phone with system dark mode disabled.

[dark mode on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnZgG.jpg)
[dark mode off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE9vd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color in the xml file to be like this one

```
android:textColor="?attr/colorSecondary"
// Which you can always change from the app Themes, Themes(night)
```

*Another solution,
Press right click on the values folder, then new file and make its name colors but down it u can find "Available qualifiers". Go further down, you can find "Night Mode" so move it to the right, and change not night to night.
After that u will have a folder called "Colors" that has 2 files, one for light mode and the other for the night mode.
Notice, u have to create a color item in the light mode first and then go with the same name to the dark mode and create a color item but with a different value.

Here is an example

```
//This is the light mode colors file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="news_bck">#16686767</color>
</resources>
```

As you might notice, the name of the color is a variable which you have to mention it after .

```
// The dark mode file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="news_bck">#86F1EDED</color>
</resources>
```

Now in the xml file of my layout, I only have to write this line to the button.

```
android:background="@color/news_bck"
```